# Solve the following homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

$a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$

$a_{0}=a_{1}=2$

$x^{2}=2x-1$

$x^{2}-2x+1=0$

$(x-1)^2=0$

$x=1$

$a_{n}=(α+βn) 1^{n}$

$(α+β(0)) 1^{0}=2$

$α=2$

$(α+β(1)) 1^{1}=2$

$α+β=2$

$a_{n}=2$

I can't seem to find of anything I did wrong. It seems weird that this would be the answer though, so I have a feeling I did something wrong. Just looking for some confirmation on my HW.

Answer (score 1):

No, everything is fine. You got that the solution is a linear function of $n$, and since the initial slope is $0$, the solution stays horizontal, i.e., constant.

Comment: Thanks, after looking at it a little longer, I came to a conclusion close to that!